# How to best track azure service bus messages through several queues/topics

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

For example:

1. Message is added to topic from a .net application
2. 2 subscriptions to topic will conditionally add messages to a queue (Queue A, Queue B, ...)
3. Each Queue from step 2 will have corresponding functions that take the message, and create a new one from it, then add it to Queue Z
4. Another function subscribes to Queue Z and sends a message via SendGrid (or some other provider)
5. Another function is an http trigger that Sendgrid will post all results to (accepted, delivered, opened, etc)

At step 4 we can add custom properties, and I think this is where we need to get some unique identifier, which will come back as part of the response we get in step 5.

The end goal is to be able to look at data received in Step 5 and link it to the message that was created in Step 1.  How do I best link steps 1, 2, and 3 so that step 4 can add a unique identifier?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but based on what you've described I believe you're trying to implement something similar to Fan out pattern of Durable Functions framework:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp

Comment: In your example I'd want to tie the messages in the queue to the left of F2 to the messages in the queue on the right of F2.  I _could_ add a custom property in F1 and then ensure other functions pass that on, but that sounds iffy at best.

Comment: I don't see another way, somehow you'll need to correlate the things, if that's what you meant

Comment: Sorry - I don't see how this solution provides a way to solve the problem, am I missing something?

Comment: I understood that Z would have to wait the process of each function from step 2, so Z, would be f3 in the sample above

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do distributed tracing https://microservices.io/patterns/observability/distributed-tracing.html

Examples for doing so in Azure would use Application Insights
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring. This would allow you to correlate service bus messages and function processing.